# Satchmo Template form.username Not Popping Up

Tags: django, django-templates, e-commerce, satchmo

## registration/login.html edited

```
{% load i18n %}
    <div id="Login">
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <p class="error">
        {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}{{ err }}
            {% if not forloop.last %}<br/>{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr><td><label for="id_username">{% trans 'USERNAME' %}:</label></td><td>{{ form.username }}</td></tr>
    {% if form.username.errors %}<tr><td class="error" colspan="2">***{{     form.username.errors|join:", " }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
    <tr><td><label for="id_password">{% trans 'PASSWORD' %}:</label></td><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr>
    {% if form.password.errors %}<tr><td class="error" colspan="2">***{{     form.password.errors|join:", " }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
</table>

<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'sign in' %}" />
{% url registration_register as registration_register %}
{% if registration_register %}
    <span><a href="{% url registration_register %}">{% trans "register" %}</a></span>
{% endif %}
<input type="hidden" name="next"
{% if next %}
    value={{ next }} />
{% else %}
     {% url satchmo_account_info as accounturl %}
     {% if accounturl %} value="{% url satchmo_account_info %}" /> {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</form>

{% comment %} We jump through hoops with the urls so it doesn't bomb with django's built in unit tests.{% endcomment %}
{% url auth_password_reset as auth_password_reset %}
{% if auth_password_reset %}
    <p>{% trans "If you do not remember your password, please" %} 
        <a href="{% url auth_password_reset %}">{% trans "click here</a> to have it reset." %}</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Why does the form.username and form.password input box not show up? I had to remove the block tag {% extends shop/base.html %}. Did that cause the input field to disappear?

What I did was removed the {% block content %}{% endblock %} and used {% include "registration/login.html" %} in the base.html template. I wanted the login section to appear at the top left corner instead of having to click "Login" for the login field located in the {% block content %}.

## registration/login.html original file

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block navbar %}
   <li class="first"><a href="{{ shop_base }}/">{% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.non_field_errors %}
<p class="error">{% for err in form.non_field_errors %}{{ err }}{% if not forloop.last %}<br/>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr><td><label for="id_username">{% trans 'Email address' %}:</label></td><td>{{ form.username }}</td></tr>
{% if form.username.errors %}<tr><td class="error" colspan="2">***{{ form.username.errors|join:", " }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
<tr><td><label for="id_password">{% trans 'Password' %}:</label></td><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr>
{% if form.password.errors %}<tr><td class="error" colspan="2">***{{ form.password.errors|join:", " }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
</table>

<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Login' %}" />
<input type="hidden" name="next"
{% if next %}
    value={{ next }} />
{% else %}
     {% url satchmo_account_info as accounturl %}
     {% if accounturl %} value="{% url satchmo_account_info %}" /> {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</form>
{% comment %} We jump through hoops with the urls so it doesn't bomb with django's built in unit tests.{% endcomment %}
{% url registration_register as registration_register %}
{% url auth_password_reset as auth_password_reset %}
{% if registration_register %}
    <p>{% trans "If you do not have an account, please" %} <a href="{% url registration_register %}">{% trans "click here" %}</a>.</p>
{% endif %}
{% if auth_password_reset %}
    <p>{% trans "If you do not remember your password, please" %} <a href="{% url auth_password_reset %}">{% trans "click here</a> to have it reset." %}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

## shop/base.html

```
 <div id="sidebar-primary">{# rightnav #}
                {% block sidebar-primary %}
                <h3>{% trans "Quick Links" %}</h3>
                {% url satchmo_product_recently_added as recenturl %}
                {% if recenturl %}<a href="{{ recenturl }}">{% trans "Recently Added" %}</a>{% endif %}
                {% url satchmo_product_best_selling as popularurl %}
                {% if popularurl %}<br/><a href="{{ popularurl }}">{% trans "Best Sellers" %}</a><br/>{% endif %}
        {% url satchmo_category_index as category_index %}
        {% if category_index %} <a href="{{ category_index }}">{% trans "Category Index" %}</a><br /> {% endif %}
        {% url satchmo_quick_order as quick_order %}
        {% if quick_order %}<a href="{{ quick_order }}">{% trans "Quick Order" %}</a> {% endif %}
                {% plugin_point "sidebar_links" %}

            <h3>{% trans "Account Information" %}</h3>
            {% if user.is_staff %}
                <a href="{% url admin:index %}" target="blank">{% trans "Admin" %}</a><br/>
                {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                {% url satchmo_account_info as accounturl %}
        {% if accounturl %}<a href="{{ accounturl }}" target="blank">{% trans "Account Details" %}</a><br/>{% endif %}
        <a href="{{ logout_url }}?next={{request.path}}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a><br/>
            {% else %}
 <!-- I REMOVE REPLACED THE LINK BELOW WITH {% include "registration/login.html" %} -->
        <a href="{{ login_url }}?next={{request.path}}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a><br/>
            {% endif %}

                {% url satchmo_cart as carturl %}
            {% if carturl %}<a href="{{ carturl }}">{% trans "Cart" %}</a>{% endif %}

            {% if not cart.is_empty %}
            ({{ cart_count|normalize_decimal }} - {% if sale %}{{ cart|discount_cart_total:sale|currency }}{% else %}{{cart.total|currency}}{% endif%}) <br/>
            {% url satchmo_checkout-step1 as checkouturl %}
            {% if checkouturl %}<a href="{{ checkouturl }}">{% trans "Check out" %}</a>{% endif %}
            {% endif %}

                {% plugin_point "shop_sidebar_actions" %}

                {% url satchmo_contact as contact_url %}
            {% if contact_url %}<p><a href="{{ contact_url }}">{% trans "Contact Us" %}</a></p>{% endif %}

                {% satchmo_language_selection_form %}

                {% block sidebar-primary-bottom %}
                {% plugin_point "shop_sidebar_primary" %}
                {% endblock %}
                {% endblock sidebar-primary %}
        </div>
```

I tried a `{% include "registration/copy_login.html" %}` and changed the content around a little. I also used `<form action="{% url auth_login %}`. When I click submit with login/pass filled out, it takes me to `/accounts/login/` where I have to enter the login data again.

This is my `copy_login.html`:

```
 # copy_login.html
 ...
 <tr><td><label for="id_username">{% trans "Username" %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="id_username" id="id_username" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><label for="id_password">{% trans "Password" %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="id_password" id="id_password" /></td></tr>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your template extends another template, then only the code it has in {% block %}...{% endblock %} is supposed to "show up".

Say i have this base.html template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in such a login.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

this won't show up because it's not in a block

{% block body %}
    this will "show up"
{% endblock %}
```

Read up about [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer specific only to user's code**

The first problem is that you probably tried to include the modified shortened registration/login.html into the main template, but you hide it into comment:

```
<!-- I REMOVE REPLACED THE LINK BELOW WITH {% include "registration/login.html" %} -->
```

Uncomment it to see the result.

The original template registration/login.html is used by the view `accounts.views.emaillogin` and used by URL `/accounts/login/` which is redirected if you go to any page that requires login. You broke it, but you want to display a bigger form in the centre of page in this case, not only the small in the corner. You also do not want display there errors related to other forms on the page. Isn't it? Do not break the purpose of the original template.

**General answer**

I recommend first to copy paste important parts of login template `registration/login.html` to your smaller template that you include somewhere. Do it so that you not include error messages etc. in the small template, only the minimum. If the login fails the usual big login page with messages will be displayed. You need to change `action="."` to

```
<form method="post" action="{% url auth_login %}?next={{ request.path }}">
```

Note: The name `auth_login` is defined in satchmo_store/accounts/urls.py by:

```
(r'^login/$', 'emaillogin', {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, 'auth_login'),
```

Finally you can make it DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself) but it's not worth the effort for you, while the templates will be very different.

[Edited] 1) Included small fix from comments. 2) Modified to be easier for others.

Comment: I used <form method="post" action="{% url auth_login %}"> and the input form on the front page but it takes me to accounts/login/ page whenever I enter username and password. Then I have to enter login details again. PS: I updated my post up there. Any idea?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a login in the front page. Something like this: http://rgmania.com/

Comment: I am sorry, it should be `<form method="post" action="{% url auth_login %}?next={{ request.path }}">` in order to redirect back or `?next=/` for redirect to homepage. I'm fixing it in the answer.

Comment: When I copy the important parts of registration/login.html to a another file like say copy_login.html, how would I go about copying the form input id_username and id_password? I tried form.username and form.password, but It doesn't show up because it's not being passed to the call. I'm missing something here even though you've done your best at explaining. What am I missing?

Comment: In the case of small login form there is no reason to have any smart fields, because user name and password are initially empty. If the login fails the username can be redisplayed in the big login form. You can replace most things by fixed parsed values, except "action", csrf token and tags for translation field names. It is not DRY, but easy.